# I need a DMS for C#.NET, and am considering WSS, how do I get started?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, wss, document-management

Our clients do not need Sharepoint, but I have been told that WSS will provide what I need for a basic DMS.  We have two web apps we need to write that stores docs, etc.  I want to demo something like this by Friday.  Where do I begin?  What do I install?  Will WSS actually involve deploying a sharepoint portal?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/demo-tour-a-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-site-HA010205563.aspx

Maybe get this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-SharePoint-Services-Developer/dp/0735623201](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick demo,. I'd suggest setting up a [BPOS](http://www.microsoft.com/online/business-productivity.aspx) account. You'll not have to worry about how to configure or install, you just have to use it. Can be up and running in a matter of minutes, for less than the cost of a couple of cups of coffee.

Plenty of references on the web about how to use it. SharePoint is fine as a basic DMS, though it really depends on what criteria you put into "basic". Best of luck with it.